# Evaluate the $I=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}\sin (a\sqrt{x})}{x}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: laplace-transform, contour-integration

I want to evaluate
$$I=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}\sin (a\sqrt{x})}{x}\,\mathrm dx$$
It seems that the solution should be in the form of the error function and also it involves contour integration.

Comment: Are $a$ and $t$ real parameters or complex ones?

Comment: My advice for you would be to first differentiate with regards to *t* inside the integral sign, then to substitute $x=u^2$ and to use Euler's formula.

Comment: To Jack, There isn't anything stated about the a and t. To Lucian, I will work on it and keep you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
I=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}\sin (a\sqrt{x})}{x}\,\mathrm dx
$$
$$
\frac{dI}{da} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}\cos (a\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm dx
\\=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-\frac{a^2}{4t}}
$$
(Abramowitz & Stegun, p 1026).

Integrating:
$$
\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}
I(a,t) = \erf { (\frac {a} {2 \sqrt{t}})} + C(t)
$$

$C(t) = 0$ since $I(0,t) = 0$, and therefore
$$
\\I= \erf { (\frac {a} {2 \sqrt{t}})}
$$

Comment: Thanks, I do not have enough reputation to give positive to your solution, but thank you. I was wondering if you have a reference for your solution or you did it on your own. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: I did it with the help of Abramowitz and Stegun, after noticing that the integral is a Laplace transform.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a,t\in\mathbb{R}^+$ we have:
$$ I = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-tx^2}\sin(ax)\frac{dx}{x}$$
where:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\frac{\partial I}{\partial a}&=&\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-tx^2}\cos(ax)\,dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\Re\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-tx^2+iax\right)\,dx\\&=&\frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{t}}\Re\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-x^2+\frac{ia}{\sqrt{t}}x\right)\,dx=\frac{2e^{-a^2/(4t)}}{\pi\sqrt{t}}\Re\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\left(x-\frac{ia}{2\sqrt{t}}\right)^2\right)\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi t}}e^{-a^2/(4t)}\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence:
$$ I = \color{red}{\operatorname{Erf}\frac{a}{2\sqrt{t}}}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I do not have enough reputation to give positive to your solution, but thank you very much. I only couldn't understand how you got the first term on the second line. Also, do you have a reference for your solution or you did it on your own. Thanks.

Comment: ok I got it, just to make it more clear: $\int_0^\infty e^{-ax^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}\,du$ just change the $ax^2$ with $u^2$ and $2axdx=2udu$.